# VideoView on landscape as splash screen

Tags: android, xml, android-videoview

I want to create a splash screen as start up. I have also created an `activity_splash.xml`. 
This is my Java code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(videoHolder);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
            videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
            videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    jump();
                }
            });
            videoHolder.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            jump();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        jump();
        return true;
    }

    private void jump() {
        if (isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want to link the VideoView to this `activity_splash.xml`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="me.smash_it.smashit.SplashScreen">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried this in my Java code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        try {
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
            .....
    }
```

When I tried that It doesn't show my Splashscreen it directly starts my other activity and that is Webview. If look at my debug I got this error:

> 11-07 08:16:49.591 7974-8029/[PROJECT_NAME] E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Does anyone know what I did wrong or what does that error means? I have tested on a real device and I still get that error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    try {
            VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            setContentView(videoHolder);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
            videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
            videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    jump();
                }
            });
            videoHolder.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            jump();
        }
```

So like you can see I use twice `setContentView` I was placing the created view in the `setContentView` what was giving me the error. Only thing I need to do was to remove this `setContentView(videoHolder);`.